# Angular routerLink varible

Tags: angular2, angular5, angular, angular-routing

Все привет подскажите есть ли возможность передать переменную внутри [routerLink] наподобие того как это реализовано в инициализации самого компонента 
`<cumponent [varible]="varible"></component>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Это не инициализация компонента.

2) Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
         <a [routerLink]="path">Обо мне</a>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public path = '/about';
}
```

Если же нужно конкатенировать пути - передавайте массив:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
         <a [routerLink]="['/about', userId, 'profile']">О юзере с айди 4</a>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public userId = 4;
}
```

Передать данные в дочерний компонент можно только через входные свойства, которые декорируются с помощью `@Input`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `
        <a [routerLink]="path">Обо мне</a>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input()
    public path: string = null;
}
```

Ну и передаем `path` как `data-bound` свойство:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <app-child [path]="path"></app-child>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public path = '/about';
}
```

Comment: В вашем варианте насколько я понимаю мы получим вида "/about/userId/profile" а идея заключалась в том чтобы осуществить взаимодействие м/у разными компонентами передав переменную из первого во второй

Comment: @se3os, вопрос не так трактовался, если передать переменную в дочерний компонент - то только через `@Input`